# Internet connection is fine but some webpage won't appear

Tags: windows-xp, internet-connection

I'm using Windows XP, and connected to LAN with many other computer.
I can access facebook, twitter, tumblr, gmail, but other website is down.
In google chrome, it displays:

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to www.samplewebsite.com Try
>   reloading: www.samplewebsite..­com Additional suggestions: Access a
>   cached copy of www.­samplewebsite.­com

And in Firefox it shows:

> XML Parsing Error: undefined entity Location:
>   jar:jar:file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Owner/Application%20Data/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/iurqfrq3.default/extensions/bandwidthmeter@gotomyhelp.com.xpi!/chrome/bandwidthmeter.jar!/content/netError.xhtml
>   Line Number 392, Column 33:

Btw, I could also access youtube.

I'm also using FTP, and I can't connect to certain websites either.

I've read the related article but what does it have to do with the `tracert` command?

*Edit*
Everytime I ping a website I cannot access it displays:
Ping request could not find host: www.samplewebsite.com Please check the name and try again.

Please help. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Are your DNS settings the same as the other computer, and can that computer access www.samplewebsite.com?

Comment: I do the tracert command, and i think the problem is in the host

Comment: If you to go http://whatismyip.com on both the working and non-working machines, do they show the same IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Try with ping and tracert commands.

Open CMD > ping www.google.com (Must get reply), Use your desired website instead of google.com

Open CMD > Tracert www.google.com (Must reach till last IP address of website)

Seems like some issue with DNS server, try changing your DNS server.